# Issue launching X11 app via NSTask

Tags: objective-c, macos, unix, pygtk

My app uses NSTask to execute shell scripts, one of those scripts launches an X11 app (specifically `meld`).

I would have expected this to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.profile                      # setup $PATH/etc
meld .
```

But it fails with:

```
gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/meld", line 132, in <module>
    gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_search_path'
```

As a proof of concept I changed the script to this, which works perfectly:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

exec 'osascript -e \'tell app "Terminal" to do script "meld ' + Dir.pwd + '" in front window\''
```

Does anyone what is causing the problem? Here is my code for executing the shell script:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
task.launchPath = self.scriptURL.path;
task.standardOutput = [NSPipe pipe];
task.currentDirectoryPath = workingDirectoryURL.path;

[task launch];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X11 apps learn the display server's address using the DISPLAY environment variable.

On OS X, the DISPLAY value is randomized for security reasons, so you can't hard-code it, as you noticed. Instead, there is a launchd agent that tells launchd to set DISPLAY when it starts a process.

Somewhere between launchd and meld, the value of DISPLAY is being dropped or overwritten. Your job is to find out where.

1. Make sure the launchd agent is running. Run `launchctl list` and look for org.macosforge.xquartz.startx. Since `meld` is working from Terminal.app this part is probably correct.
2. Make sure DISPLAY is set in your app. It should be listed in `[NSProcessInfo processInfo].environment`.
3. Make sure DISPLAY is set in the NSTask you launch. Try running `/usr/bin/env` with an NSTask, and make sure DISPLAY appears in its output.
4. Make sure DISPLAY is set inside the script you run. Try `echo $DISPLAY` before and after sourcing ~/.profile. (Sometimes the .profile itself overwrites DISPLAY to an incorrect value because that's sometimes the right thing to do on other operating systems.)

**EDIT:** this is the code I used to copy DISPLAY from my GUI app to the shell script:

```
NSTask *task = ...
task.environment = [NSProcessInfo processInfo].environment;
[task.launch];
```

Comment: Item 2 in your list was the issue. I had to manually copy ENV from my GUI app to the shell script it was launching. Perhaps this would normally be done automatically but I was setting other environment variables, which might have stomped all over it.

Answer (score 1):

Change your script to spew the environment variables and compare "working" to "not-working".

There are subtle differences between how shells are initialized across the different execution models.  Almost assuredly, the environment is the source of your issues.

Comment: Thanks! I needed this: `export DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-e6qXkg/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`. It looks like the value changes on every reboot however, so I'll need to look into it further...

Comment: There ought to be something in the X11 environment that spews the DISPLAY variable once launched, given that it is dynamically set.  (Been too long since I've mucked w/X).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at man launchctl

launchctl submit ... -p /usr/local/bin/meld -- .

to have launchd launch the job; that will set certain environment variables for you that are part of the per-user session.