# xQuartz display not for shell script launched from Swift Process

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a simple shell script which launches an X11 app. When I execute this shell script form my login shell / terminal xQuartz starts and I get a display. However the process doesn't get a display for xQuartz when running the script from within swift. Any idea how I can get the display?

Also what is the best way to detect if xQuartz is installed? Checking if xterm exists?

```
   let process = Process()

    process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/sh")
    let startScriptURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "run", withExtension: "sh")
    guard let startScriptPath = startScriptURL?.path else {
        return
    }
    process.arguments = [startScriptPath]

    do {
    try process.run()
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
```

run.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
/opt/X11/bin/xeyes
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured our how to pass the `DISPLAY` environment or any environmental variable to Process.

The current environment can be obtained by:

`ProcessInfo().environment`

So I use now this:

```
let process = Process()
guard let envDisplay = ProcessInfo().environment["DISPLAY"] else {
    print("Please install xQuartz")
    return
}

process.environment = ["DISPLAY": envDisplay]
```

I got the idea from here: [Issue launching X11 app via NSTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650151/issue-launching-x11-app-via-nstask)